# Convert XSDs to Protos

Tags: java, .net, xml, xsd, protocol-buffers

I have a set of services coupled with whole bunch of XSDs. Clients that use my service use XML and in the future will use protobufs. Is there a tool out there that will convert my XSDs into proto files?

The plan here is to define the interface once using XSD and then autogenerate the protos so that both interfaces remain in sync.

Comment: Actually, since .proto is a more limited syntax (not as many options) I'd be tempted to work the other way around....

Comment: That's a good point Marc, but some projects starting point will be XSD that they use to generate domain classes. In the past we've used http://xmlbeans.apache.org/ to generate our dto classes and developed protomak to automatically create proto files for these dto's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it might fit the bill for you:

https://github.com/tranchis/xsd2thrift

I haven't used it myself, but the project description sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: sadly, LGPL software is not allowed in my company.

Answer (score 1):

**Protomak** is a tool dedicated to exactly this task.

- https://github.com/mtedone/protomak/ {**source code**}
- http://www.jemos.eu/projects/protomak/ {**project website**}

The lastest release supports:

- **Xsd** to **Proto** files with support for

  - Anonymous types
  - Complex types
  - Inherited complex types
  - Restrictions for enumerations
- **Maven** plugin
- **Ant** build task

Disclaimer: I worked on this project

Comment: the license associated with this (MIT) is accepted by my company whereas xsd2thift is not as it is LGPL. Also fits our solution better as it contains an ANT task.

Comment: http://www.jemos.eu/projects/protomak/ is not working ?can you please post the new link.where to find any sample example ?